# Bash "if" condition being executed no matter what

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm new to bash scripting, and, while I know this is undoubtably a duplicate question, I can't figure out how to word it to search for it.

```
for i in $( ls); do
    FILETYPE=$( file -b $i )
    if [ "$FILETYPE"="Apple binary property list" ]; then
        echo $FILETYPE
    else 
        echo "nope"
    fi
done
```

I'm expecting this to ONLY print
"Apple binary property list"
when the statement succeeds and to ONLY print "nope" otherwise.

What's happening is that it's printing the filetype regardless of whether the statement succeeds or fails, and never prints "nope".

I know it's something simple, but can someone please tell me why it's printing anything other than "Apple binary property list" and "nope",
and what i can do to fix it?

Comment: Try adding some spaces between the strings in the condition, like `"$FILETYPE" = "..."`

Comment: Use shellcheck.net to find obvious mistakes in your script

Comment: my question is why is it doing whats in the if, if the statement is not true... i'd understand if it only printed "nope" but it makes zero sense to me why it would echo $filetype if the condition is failing

Comment: anubhava, you're a champion. thats awesome. Joachim, you were right, if you add that as an answer, i'll give u the checkmark :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use this:

```
for i in $( ls); do
```

as it will break when filenames contain spaces or characters like `*`. Use this:

```
for i in *; do
```

The `*` expands to the list of all files in the directory.

---

Don't forget to quote your shell variables, for related reasons:

```
FILETYPE=$( file -b "$i" )
```

This passes the whole variable as a single argument, which is what you want.

---

`[` is a command which takes a list of arguments, separated by whitespace:

```
if [ "$FILETYPE" = "Apple binary property list" ]; then
```

Without the spaces, `[` only sees two arguments, `"$FILETYPE"="Apple binary property list"` and `]`.

---

Again, use quotes around variables:

```
    echo "$FILETYPE"
```

Comment: "[ is a command which takes a list of arguments, separated by whitespace" = mind blown

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the square-bracket `[` is a command, it's an alias for the [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) command, and as all commands it expects its arguments to be separated by spaces.

When you write (without any spacing)

```
"$FILETYPE"="Apple binary property list"
```

that is a *single* argument to the [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) command, and it uses that single arguments as a non-empty string which will always be true.

When you add spaces, like

```
"$FILETYPE" = "Apple binary property list"
```

the [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) command has three arguments and will parse it correctly as a string, an operation and another string.